# What is better in Android? Timer or Alarm?

Tags: java, android, timer, alarm

I am developing an app for android that measures some network parameters every hour. I already have the code to do the measurements, so I only need some help on how to make it do it periodically. What should I use? Timers, Alarms or something else? Do you have any easy example on how it works?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The only good answer is to use `AlarmManager`. Having a service that sits for an hour waiting for the hour to pass is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

Using a service (so that you're not tied to an activity) you can use Handler.postAtTime to schedule a task in the future

[Handler.postAtTime](http://bit.ly/wG3gNE)

Answer (score 0):

Both should work. How about a service that runs in the background?

Comment: That's actually what I want to do.

I know this is kind of basic, but I'm still just learning... Do you know any tutorial/example to use service?

Answer (score 0):

A service may or may not be shut down by the OS. A scheduled task may or may not start because the device might be in "deep sleep" mode.
Yo should double check this, use a service and also schedule a task, if the task opens, verify with a lock or any device you want and work accordingly. That way you are almost certain that the readings will be done.